# URL regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex, url-validation

I am trying to find a regular expression that will validate as many urls as possible. I'm using it in an input field in MVC3:

```
[RegularExpression(@"expression...")]
```

I found [this regular expression - "diegoperini"](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex), and I loved it but I dont know how to convert it to .net version from php:

```
_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})
(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})
(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])
(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))
|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.
(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*
(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

How would it look in net?

Comment: I'm not sure anyone besides the author can debug that one.

Comment: That is an impressive regex, you have found!

Comment: That said, have you tried using it in something like RegexBuddy to see if it tells you where the syntax error occurs?

Comment: That said, the Perini one sees to be available in an expanded, commented version: https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294 - try to see if that bugs out, and edit your question to use that instead?

Comment: Anyone who invented Regex shoud go to hell. This is harder to debug than assembler...

Comment: Also: why does your regex start with an `_` and end with `_iuS` outside the `^…$` bits? Those seem out of place. The `iuS` stuff looks like flags actually, which are probably set differently in .NET

Comment: @millimoose, thats a good idea, they look like regex delimiters and are of course not needed in .net and the flags are set differently.

Comment: A validation regex may run on server (.net) or client side (JavaScript). You can use the `Uri` class for a good url parser, I wouldn't bother too much with that regex... Here's a simpler one, for your consideration: `^(?:http|ftp)s?://$[^.]+\.`. Basically: anything that starts with http and has a dot. Good enough. (ok, you can check for spaces, etc, but it never ends)

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at this. [diegoperini regex source](https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294)
There you will find a better readable version of diegoperini's regex. And the best - it's also commented. ;)

Comment: I see.Very usefull point ;)

Comment: Now you have two problems.

Comment: Try this "^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x00A1-\xFFFF}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x00a1-\xffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x00a1-\xffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x00a1-\xffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x00a1-\xffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$"

Comment: Many URL regexes **don't work with IPv6 addresses** - this seems to be true for the perini one as well.

Comment: @KobbyPemson I think \x isn't the same in .NET. you should use \u0000 instead of \x{0000} for example. 

`^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$`

Comment: Why does it have to be regex? Can you just use Uri.TryParse?

Comment: Ok.I can write own filter -> implement IClientValidatable,.. .But I encourented next problem: I am a big fun of layered solution structure.I cant placed this new filter in solution.enttity project or in another project.Solution will not be compiled then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to remove the PHP-delimiters and change the \x{0000}-patterns with \u0000.
So the regex should look like this.

```
String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
Regex re = new Regex(@"^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
Match m = re.Match(sourcestring);
for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
{
   Console.WriteLine("[{0}] = {1}", re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
}
```

If you want, you can see a live example [over here](http://www.myregextester.com/?r=680b6bee).

Just a short note: This pattern will match a full URL (including username, password, port, path, query, fragment), but it only does detailed validation of the domain part; the other parts are scantily validated. (Thanks to @nhahtdh for clue)

Comment: Nice! I think you have saved a lot of time to other net developers.Thanks once again!

Comment: The `\/` (3 instances) can be simplified to `/`, since there is no more need for escaping. By the way, this only validate the domain name, not the entire URL.

Comment: @nhahtdh - fixed the three intances of `\/` - thanks for your advise. Concerning the pattern - the OP asked for a .NET version of a given regex pattern. If he had asked for a pattern which matches whole urls, I hadn't posted this answer. ;)

Comment: @netblognet: I don't blame you for the URL/domain part. I just leave a note for later visitor to know that this is not regex for full URL.

Comment: @nhahtdh No problem. I'll take your note and attach it to my answer, so "later visitors" will find it easier (without reading all comments).

Comment: Just as an FYI to people that read this answer - which is great and I use it - when using it on some invalid URLs it can cause an infinite loop in .NETs regEx to occur. We worked around this by using the timeout constructor with 100 ms. An example of one that caused infinite loop:  http://Visitourfacebookpage-jingleAllTheWayNursery